# Connecting Drupal 7 Ubercart with PayPal

Tags: paypal, drupal-7

This seems like it should be a relatively easy process. There are quite a few links that come up addressing the issue in a Google search and in searches here, but something is missing in actual implementation.

My client has a PayPal account already. I have Ubercart installed with products available. But, when I go to Store -> Payment Methods -> Credit Card Settings, I cannot see any place to enter PayPal API information. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and putting bits and pieces together, I found out that the problem wasn't with Ubercart at all!

1. I could not get any clear answers for the combination of Drupal 7, Ubercart and PayPal from any website that came up from a search.
2. All of the sites listed gave me instructions to do steps with form items that did not exist in the site.
3. I figured that there was possibly a PayPal module that I was missing, but I could not find one.
4. There is indeed a module, but it turns out that the module is part of the basic Ubercart install.
5. I could not enable this module.
6. Then I found out that the reason I could not enable it is that cURL was not enabled in the server. So, I enabled it in php.ini.

So, the problem was not with Drupal 7 or with Ubercart or with a module. The problem was a php.ini setting!